# COnverting integral into First Order of Bessel Fuuction of first kind

Tags: mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, approximate-integration

How to prove

$$
\frac {\omega^2 \int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} \sin \left(\Omega s\right) \sin \left(A \cos  \left(\Omega s\right) \right)ds}{\int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} A \sin  \left(\Omega s \cos  \left(\Omega s \right)\right)ds} =  \frac {2 \omega^2 J_1 \left(A\right)}{A}, 
$$

with $\omega, \Omega, A$  being constants, where  $J_1(A)$ stands for the first order Bessel function of the first kind.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you've tried for proving the identity.

Comment: first, i think that i can change the left hand side form into {\omega^2 \int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} 2 \sin \left(\Omega s\right) \sin \left(A \cos \left(\Omega s\right) \right)ds}{\int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} 2A \sin \left(\Omega s \cos \left(\Omega s \right)\right)ds}  but the denumerator result is zero, so the equation will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

first, i think that i can change the left hand side form into $$\frac{{\omega^2 \int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} 2 \sin \left(\Omega s\right) \sin \left(A \cos \left(\Omega s\right) \right)ds}}{{\int_0 ^{2\pi/\Omega} 2A \sin \left(\Omega s \cos \left(\Omega s \right)\right)ds}}$$ but the denumerator result is zero, so the equation will be undefined. and now i still seek an idea to decompose the integral above into first order of bessel equation of the first kind.